# Make a light replicate the behavior of another light - Gazebo Classic

Tags: gazebo-plugin, gazebo-11

I have multiple point lights in my Gazebo environment. I'm controlling the Flashing of one of those lights with the [FlashlightPlugin](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=flashlight_plugin&cat=plugins). I want to make the other lights follow what the 1st light is doing without explicitly coding up the entire behavior again (did this for the 1st light). Is this possible?